# Apache Caching JS CSS Files

Tags: php, performance, apache, caching, http-headers

I have enabled mod_cache, mod_expires, mod_headers modules in my httpd.conf and also added following text

```
 ExpiresActive On


<ifModule mod_deflate.c>
  <filesMatch "\.(css|js|x?html?|php)$">
    SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
  </filesMatch>
</ifModule>



<ifModule mod_expires.c>
  ExpiresActive On
  ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 seconds"
  ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 2592000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 2592000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 2592000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 2592000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 2592000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 604800 seconds"
  ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 216000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 216000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 216000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 600 seconds"
  ExpiresByType application/xhtml+xml "access plus 600 seconds"
</ifModule>



<ifModule mod_headers.c>
  <filesMatch "\.(ico|jpe?g|png|gif|swf)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000, public"
  </filesMatch>
  <filesMatch "\.(css)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, public"
  </filesMatch>
  <filesMatch "\.(js)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=216000, public"
  </filesMatch>
  <filesMatch "\.(x?html?|php)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=600, public"
  </filesMatch>
</ifModule>



<ifModule mod_headers.c>
  Header unset ETag
</ifModule>
FileETag None



<ifModule mod_headers.c>
  Header unset Last-Modifiedd
</ifModule>


<IfModule mod_cache.c>

LoadModule mem_cache_module modules/mod_mem_cache.so
<IfModule mod_mem_cache.c>
CacheEnable mem /
MCacheSize 4096
MCacheMaxObjectCount 100
MCacheMinObjectSize 1
MCacheMaxObjectSize 2048
</IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

but files are not caching. I get headers information like

```
 Response
Date    Tue, 23 Aug 2011 11:30:09 GMT
Server  Apache/2.2.19 (Win32) PHP/5.3.6
Last-Modified   Mon, 22 Aug 2011 21:24:19 GMT
Accept-Ranges   bytes
Cache-Control   max-age=216000, public
Expires Thu, 25 Aug 2011 23:30:09 GMT
Vary    Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding    gzip
Content-Length  2875
Keep-Alive  timeout=5, max=100
Connection  Keep-Alive
Content-Type    application/javascript

Request Headers

Host    workflowsf.com
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:2.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0.1
Accept  */*
Accept-Language en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Charset  ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Keep-Alive  115
Connection  keep-alive
```

Have u any idea where I am wrong?
Thanks in advance

Comment: How do you see that the files are not caching ? Response headers seems correct (`Cache-Control: max-age=216000, public` `Expires: Thu, 25 Aug 2011 23:30:09 GMT`)

Comment: When I see status with Firebus's Net Tab then it shows me Status 200. Is it right?

Answer (score 1):

That looks like a fairly good config. You have a typo with your `Header unset Last-Modifiedd` and also you probably don't need the first line as it is a duplicate of the line inside `<ifModule mod_expires.c>` and that is a better place for it.