# CSS doesn´t update at Chrome

Tags: css, apache, google-chrome, menu, text-indent

I'm trying to make a menu in the webpage I'm actually developing, and I've noticed that the css for the menu ul doesn't update as I change code.
It doesn't update in Chrome 37.0.2062.124, but it does in Firefox 32.0.1 when I clear cache (of course, I've tried Ctrl+F5 at Chrome, too). Maybe it's interesting to know that IE 11.0.10 has the same problem than Chrome.

At this point, I want to reduce the **text indent** from 2.75 to 0.75, to fit text.
Here is the jsfiddle (where it seems to update changes):
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jjimenezg/ca11vaek/)

The problem seems to be at

```
#menu ul,
#menu ul ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;

    display: block;
    line-height: 2.75em;    
    text-indent: 0.75em;
}
```

So I don't know if that is probably an issue caused by Chrome, Apache (I'm using XAMPP 3.2.1 for W7) or any other silly stuff...

Thanks to everyone.

Comment: try menu, tools, clear browsing data, check cached

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9560447/preventing-caching-of-css-files) is a similar question about apache caching. And [here](http://css-tricks.com/can-we-prevent-css-caching/) also good article.

Try adding version postfix to your css file, it should force browser to take latest version from server.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css?v=1" />
```

Or you can add timestamp instead of version.

Comment: Or disable caches while working, because you want the browser to cache css normally.

Comment: I didn't find it because I didn't also know how to search for at all... So sorry. Thank you very much I'll try to learn how to do it well

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use Ctrl+F5, this refreshes the page without using your browsercache.

Comment: I had already done it and it was not working for me. Thank you for answering